# Angular2 .json() Acts Different on Chromium and Firefox

Tags: json, rest, firefox, angular, typescript

I have a REST application and there is a function that makes POST request to a server. The server's response is a JSON object. In this function there is a line as:

```
http.post(...)
    .map(response => response.json()) // here
    .subscribe(...)
```

I am trying it on both Chromium and Firefox. On Chromium, it works well. However on Firefox, it gives

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Is there a reasonable explanation of this? I checked the response and it is a valid JSON object.

Comment: it may happen when data returned null and you are trying to parse to json

Comment: No, I checked it and it never could be null. Also if it's so, why does Chromium not giving an error?

Comment: can you please `console.log(response._body)` before you call `.json()` and add the result to your question? (`response._body` is private but you can access it for debug purpose)

Comment: `{
  "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><h1>Operation Outcome</h1><table border=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"font-weight: bold;\">information</td><td>[]</td><td><pre>Successfully created resource &quot;Condition/114333/_history/1&quot; in 14ms</pre></td>\n\t\t\t</tr>\n\t\t</table>\n\t</div>"
  },
  "issue": [
    {
      "severity": "information",
      "code": "informational",
      "diagnostics": "Successfully created resource \"Condition/114333/_history/1\" in 14ms"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: This is unreadable. Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I think its content is not important, it is a valid JSON object.